# I need help solving the multiple radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

x = "1.html";
y = "2.html";

function redirectPage(f){
   for(var i=0; i<f.length; i++) {
      if(f.answerq[i].checked && f.answerw[i].checked && f.answere[i].checked) {
         if (f.answerq[i].value == 'a' && f.answerw[i].value == 'a' && f.answere[i].value == 'a') {
            window.location = x;
         }else {
            window.location = y;
         }
      }
   }    
}
</script>
```

```html
<form method="post" action="#">
    
*ARE YOU 18+ YEARS OLD?
<label><input type="radio" name="answerq" value="a"> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="answerq" value="b"> No</label>

*ARE YOU A U.S CITIZEN?
<label><input type="radio" name="answerw" value="a"> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="answerw" value="b"> No</label>

*ARE YOU MARRIED? 
<label><input type="radio" name="answere" value="a"> Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="answere" value="b"> No</label>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" onclick="redirectPage(this.form)">Submit!</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

 </form>
```

Selecting yes,yes,yes or no,no,no is working perfectly fine and redirect to the correct link. However, when selecting yes,yes,no, no,yes,no or yes,no,yes doesn't work after clicking the submit button.

And one more thing anyone here can help me put a validation if they do not select a radio button like an alert of prompt?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: if i select yes, yes, no,  it should redirect to 1.html after clicking the submit button

Answer (score 0):

the way to do that, with `required` and `name` attribute on your `<form`

> to make sure that the user select a radio button to all this question

```js
const
  myForm = document.forms['my-form']
, x = '1.html'
, y = '2.html'
  ; 
myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault(); // disable submit
  
  let val = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(myForm)); // get inputs
 
  // window.location =
  let window_location = (val.answerq === 'a' 
                      && val.answerw === 'a' 
                      && val.answere === 'a'
                        ) ? x : y ;
                    
  console.log( window_location );
  setTimeout( console.clear, 2500 );
  }
```

```css
fieldset { border : none; }
```

```html
<form name="my-form" >
    <fieldset>
      *ARE YOU 18+ YEARS OLD?
      <label><input type="radio" name="answerq" value="a" required> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answerq" value="b"> No</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      *ARE YOU A U.S CITIZEN?
      <label><input type="radio" name="answerw" value="a"  required> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answerw" value="b"> No</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      *ARE YOU MARRIED?
      <label><input type="radio" name="answere" value="a" required> Yes</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="answere" value="b"> No</label>
    </fieldset>
   
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

    <button type="reset"> reset </button>
  </form>
```